# How can i start a bash and after then my script

Tags: python, bash, scripting

Script 1:

```
import time
print('Wait')
time.sleep (10)
print('Start')
```

Script 2:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time

camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()

while(1):
    time.sleep(100)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview
```

How can I say to Script 1 start after sleep the second Script 
at Autostart?
Because I have use the second script with crontab and I can't execute it when it has started.

So I want to try to start from `.config/autostart/` with a .desktop script.

Comment: Please fix the syntax & indentation errors in Script 2.

Comment: I don´t have errors.

Comment: Yes you did, but now you don't. ;)

Comment: Okay and what is now the solution ?

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear to me. I think you're saying that you start Script 2 as a cron job, and now you need a way to stop it and start it using another script. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

## Add your program's path into .bashrc file

Comment: Hi @OguzcanTurk, could you add more detail to your answer? If you're unsure please check the help center on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).